# Is the click event no longer working on iOS devices?

Tags: javascript, ios

At the risk of sounding like Carly Rae Jepsen, this is crazy but I think this was working until yesterday after I updated my iOS to 10.3.3:

```js
$(document).on('click','div',clicked)
function clicked() {
 alert('yay!')
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<div>click this div tag</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your snippet works for me in 10.3.3 and displays the alert on tap/click.

Comment: And it still working (Tested on iOS 10.3.3 Google Chrome). Do you have an error message? Are you in webview, wkwebview, navigator? Do you implement a javascript interface?

Comment: Now I can't get it out of my head, thanks.

Comment: Edit: I've simplified the html and have now tried it on Google Chrome and Safari on an iPad and an iPhone.

Comment: Check #2 (No event bubbling without a cursor style) on http://www.shdon.com/blog/2013/06/07/why-your-click-events-don-t-work-on-mobile-safari

Comment: @James That was it! Thank you SO very much! In my initial post here, I had included cursor:pointer just as a lark. Then when I went back to simplify it even further, I had removed it. Thank you so very very much!

Answer (score 0):

James pointed out above that you have to have a cursor style for it to work:

```css
div {
cursor:pointer
}
```